# condition(order by) in foreach on codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, foreach, sql-order-by

i have one model function to get data from db and in view i want to show the data in two categories.

so is there any way to print data with two foreach function ?

in simple word i have a content and views table, just i want to show the new inserted data and also the most viewed data in a range of date from these tables.
i just sent title, date, user_views and published_date to view file.

this is my model function:

```
public function recent($language)
{
    $lang=$language;
    $data = $this->db
                    ->select('title,content.id,published_up','view')
                    ->from('content')
                    ->join('views','content.id = views.content_id')

                    ->where('content.language',$lang)
                    ->where('content.published_up BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND CURDATE()')
                    ->where('content.state','1')
                    ->limit('10')       
                    ->order_by("published_up","DESC")

                    ->get();

    if ($data->num_rows > 0) {

        return $data->result();
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is my view :

```
<?php foreach($recent => $item){
    echo $item->title;
} ?>
```

now if i want to show the most viewed content is there any other query or other kind of foreach?

Answer (score 0):

Use this one...
I dont know whats your fields on table.

```
public function recent($language)
{
$lang=$language;
$query = "
SELECT 
   title,content.id,published_up
FROM 
   content,views
WHERE 
   content.id = views.content_id and
   content.language = $lang and
   content.published_up BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND CURDATE() and
   content.state = 1 and
   content.state = 1 ORDER BY 
   published_up DESC LIMIT 10";

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {

    return $this->db->query($query)->result();
}else{
    return false;
}
```

}

And the loop (in view)

```
<?php
  foreach($data as $item){
    $item->title;
  }
?>
```